# Update NULL with same column having data in any row above NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have data like following script. I want to update null column with data of the same column but with any row which is not null, in same column.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Country NVARCHAR(100), County NVARCHAR(100),
                     Street NVARCHAR(100), Name NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl 
VALUES('England', 'County1', 'A Street', 'James'),
('', '', '', 'Deen'),
('', '', 'B Street', 'Adam'),
('', '', 'C Street', 'Max'),
('', 'County2', 'Y Street', 'Dax'),
('', '', '', 'Dax'),
('', '', '', 'Pax'),
('France', 'County i', 'Street ix', 'Chris'),
('', '', '', 'Crai'),
('', '', '', 'Adam')
```

After update the table should look like following:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Country NVARCHAR(100), County NVARCHAR(100),
                     Street NVARCHAR(100), Name NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl 
VALUES('England', 'County1', 'A Street', 'James'),
('England', 'County1', 'A Street', 'Deen'),
('England', 'County1', 'B Street', 'Adam'),
('England', 'County1', 'C Street', 'Max'),
('England', 'County2', 'Y Street', 'Dax'),
('England', 'County2', 'Y Street', 'Dax'),
('England', 'County2', 'Y Street', 'Pax'),
('France', 'County i', 'Street ix', 'Chris'),
('France', 'County i', 'Street ix', 'Crai'),
('France', 'County i', 'Street ix', 'Adam')

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

I am reading this from Excel Sheet. If this is not possible then I can ask user to add a row number like ID in first column of Excel Sheet. Will that work?

Thanks!

Comment: what are you ordering by? Without something concrete to set the row order any results would be potentially different each time you run this

Comment: Do you really run an insert, or do you plan to update an existing table? If you insert, you could assign Country, County and Street to variables which you reset whenever the value is not null. Let me know if that is the case and I'll prepare an example.

Comment: See my edit, I think I should explain it more.

Comment: Oh, and where are the values coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use option with CTE

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Id
  FROM tbl
  ), cte2 AS
 (
  SELECT Id, Country, County, Street, Name
  FROM cte
  WHERE Id = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.Id, COALESCE(c.Country, c2.Country), 
               COALESCE(c.County, c2.County), 
               COALESCE(c.Street, c2.Street), c.Name
  FROM cte c JOIN cte2 c2 ON  c.Id = c2.Id + 1
  )
  UPDATE c
  SET c.Country = c2.Country,
      c.County = c2.County,
      c.Name = c2.Name,
      c.Street = c2.Street
  FROM cte c JOIN cte2 c2 ON c.Id = c2.Id
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b143/1)

Comment: `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` doesn't guarantee any particular ordering such as insert order.

Comment: @Muhammad Kashif Nadeem if add column ID(numbering correspond to an order as in your example) then you can to use my script without fears.Only replace Id on your new Id

Answer (score 1):

Entries in table are unordered, so it's impossible to do, unless you define an order yourself (with "order by" )